# BNF FORM of odd numbers

Tags: bnf

How to write Odd number in BNF form?

Comment: Next time please post what you've tried so far

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the odd digits separately.

```
odd ::= "1","3","5","7","9"
```

Then define a group containing all digits

```
digit ::= odd, "2","4","6","8","0"
```

Finally, define odd numbers as any number of digits ending with an odd using recursion

```
number ::= number digit | digit
oddnumber ::= number odd | odd
```